# Warming up when getting out of bed in morning

Tags: home, substitute-tool, comfort

My bedroom has a heating problem. It's very cold in the morning. I bought a fan electric heater which works great. However I normally don't leave it on at night as it gets too hot and makes noise. I would like to be able to turn it on without getting out of my bed, for example by using a smart phone app or remote control. There aren't any electrical outlets close enough to my bed to allow me to turn it on without getting out. Buying a heavy duty extension cord is an idea, but seems like a waste as I'll be moving in a couple months and wouldn't need it. I've tried with a regular extension chord and the wattage is too much. Any ideas? I'd say it meats "looking for simple and practical tips to life's everyday problems that may not have an obvious solution"

Forgot to mention that utilities are included in the rent so I don't pay more for electricity. Why the close votes?

Comment: This isn't a way to turn it on remotely, but if you want it to be on at the same time daily, you could use a timer adapter. They fit in the socket and then the appliance is plugged in to the adapter which has a clock which can be set for allowing power through or preventing power.

Comment: @Dave I recommend you to post your comment as an answer, since **it is** an answer, and probably the simplest/cheapest one

Comment: They make products for this, it doesnt really seem to need a hack. You aren't the first with this problem and its not unsolved. Just search for wireless power switches or cheap timers. Add the word "app" to the search if you're looking for one with phone app support. The answers here will probably end up just being a list of favorite remote control and home automation projects.

Comment: Btw, an extension cord might come in handy for other things later or you could give it away or sell it on craigslist or something when you're done... you mentioned it was a "waste", is something preventing you from finding a good home for it when you're done with it? It doesn't *have* to go in a trash can when you no longer need it. If you're talking about cost just pretend it's offset by a lower electric bill turning the heater off at night.

Answer (score 5):

Just get yourself a timer which you can plug into the socket and plug the heater into the timer socket. 
The alternative would be to accept the cold bedroom. There is no quicker way to wake up and be be spritely early on a winter morning.

Comment: Actually, I personally think cold makes me dread getting up. A heater on a timer is a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Belkin WeMo switch. You can plug your heater into that, and then control it with your smartphone or tablet over wifi. I think even IFTTT works with WeMo, also.